# Ever increasing silhouette width and Mantel statistics when seeking optimal number of clusters in hierarchical agglomerative clustering

Tags: r, clustering, multivariate-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, hac

When wanting to identify the optimum number of clusters in my hierarchical agglomerative clustering attempt (UPGMA and complete linkage), I obtain ever increasing **average silhouette widths** (Rousseeuw quality index) and **Mantel correlation coefficients** with increasing number of clusters. Hoping to obtain a limited amount of well interpretable clusters, this is clearly not what I want. Have I gone wrong or is this a true result? And if so: Should I use another tool to identify interpretable clusters or choose an arbitrary k?

Aim of the project is to identify clusters of 10,000 descriptors in a data set with 750 objects. I follow the procedure outlined in *Numerical Ecology with R* by Borcard,  Gillet and Legendre (2011). I have tested clustering based on absolute (count) and binary (presence/absence) versions of the data set; both lead to the described issue. UPGMA and complete linkage clusters were identified as best representations of the data using cophenetic correlation and Gower distance.

When I then run computation and plotting of silhouette widths, average silhouette width ever increases with the number of groups (at least within the range tested - I stopped the calculations at 600+ groups). The same accounts for the comparison between the Jaccard distance matrix and the binary matrices representing partitions of the hierarchical clusters: Their correlation is constantly rising with k, the number of groups.

[image: Ever increasing avg silhouette width with k (number of groups)]

[image: ...and Mantel correlations between original distance matrix and binary matrices cut from the dendrogramm are no better.]

Answer (score 2):

Late, and partial. Take this as a suggestion, not an answer, as I'm also just learning this field right now.

1) Evaluate your number of clusters with a measure such as the Gap statistic (*Estimating the number of clusters in a data set via the gap statistic*,  Tibshirani, R., Walther, G., Hastie, T., 2001. Journal of the Royal Statistical Society: Series B (Statistical Methodology) 63, 411–423. https://doi.org/10.1111/1467-9868.00293 https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/gap.pdf), prediction strength (*Cluster Validation by Prediction Strength*, Tibshirani, R., Walther, G., 2005. Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics 14, 511–528. https://doi.org/10.1198/106186005X59243, http://statweb.stanford.edu/~gwalther/predictionstrength.pdf), or several others, which includes an evaluation of *k* = 1 -- i.e., no good clustering -- as an option.

2) Have a look at how many elements are in each of your clusters. In my case, with the Gap statistic giving monotonically better fits with increasing *k*, the increasing number of clusters was just overfitting -- each new cluster was peeling off a single observation into its own cluster. The consensus matrices from consensus clustering (library `ConsensusClusterPlus` in R) can also offer a clue. Does the heatmap look block diagonal for any *k,* or does increasing *k* just give tiny blocks along the diagonal with the rest of the data in a large fuzzy square?

3) Also -- if the y axis scale in the first plot is to be believed, those silhouette widths are all tiny?

(Finally, with 10,000 predictors, are you using Euclidean distance? *On the Surprising Behavior of Distance Metrics in High Dimensional Space*, Aggarwal, C.C., Hinneburg, A., Keim, D.A., 2001. in: Database Theory — ICDT 2001, Lecture Notes in Computer Science. Presented at the International Conference on Database Theory, Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg, pp. 420–434. https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-44503-X_27, https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-44503-X_27.pdf.)